# onchange event to html.editfor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an input box that is created in razor using Html.EditorFor.

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.Person.FirstName)`

I would like to add a change event to this box so that some code will trigger if the value changes.

I have tried this jquery:

```
$('#person_Person_FirstName').change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
}).change();
```

But I'm not getting anything.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: My guess is the "person_Person_FirstName" DOM element is rendered after the jquery code is loaded. Since the element does not exist in the DOM yet your jquery code above will not work. Try moving the jquery code after the razor code, or if you have already done that try using .on instead: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Also try adding your above jQuery to `$(document).ready(function(){ //...above code here });` to the end of your file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on('change','#person_Person_FirstName', function() {
       alert($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the actual id of that rendered element, then doing this should work:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#person_Person_FirstName').change(function () {
    console.log( this.value );
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `$(document).ready(function(){ //...above code here })` worked